# how to get a footer div to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for hours now couldn't find any solution for my problem I've made my footer stick to the bottom by `position:fixed;bottom:0;` the footer gets to bottom but when my content is more the footer doesn't expand to the bottom relative to the content so i've did this made a container div and placed my footer in it

```
<div id="container">
<div id="body">
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</div>

#container
{
   position:relative;
}
#footer
{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   height:30px;
}
```

so far so good but when i try to increase my footer size(height) to 300PX it occupies my entire page I just want the footer to be at bottom with same height i have even tried making the `#body{min-height:500px;}` but my footer still doesn't go down with 300px of height.

To be exact i want a footer like stackoverflow but when there is no content i should still stick to bottom with a min body height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please follow the link http://jsfiddle.net/cooolkiran/yVC8r/

```
 <div class="page-wrap"> Content</div>
<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>


    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .page-wrap {
      min-height: 100%;
      /* equal to footer height */
      margin-bottom: -142px; 
    }
    .page-wrap:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
    }
    .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
      /* .push must be the same height as footer */
      height: 142px; 
    }
    .site-footer {
      background: orange;
    }
```

Comment: hey bro this does the same as what i have tried when there is no content i want the footer to stick to the bottom with a min of container height.

Comment: @maniteja yes when there is no content the footer will stick to the bottom. check the same updated version with less content http://jsfiddle.net/yVC8r/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

to your CSS and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace -

```
    <div id="container">
    <div id="body">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    </div>
```

with following code - (try with closing div id="body" after footer division)

```
   <div id="container">
   <div id="body">
   <div id="footer"> 
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nMVA5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="body">
this is body
</div>
<div id="footer">
this is footer
</div>
</div>

#container
{
border:solid red thin;
position:relative;
height:100px;
}
#footer
{
border:solid red thin;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
height:30px;
width:100%;
}
```

demo link:http://jsfiddle.net/yVC8r/2/